# AndroidRuntime thrashing

Tags: android, logcat

I get this series of messages about once every six or so seconds from my Android emulator's LogCat output. I haven't noticed a cause, and it doesn't always happen, but when it does, it doesn't stop until I kill the emulator. Here's the repeated message:

```
07-28 20:53:00.763: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2756): Shutting down VM
07-28 20:53:00.763: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2756): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
07-28 20:53:00.802: INFO/AndroidRuntime(2756): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
07-28 20:53:01.682: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2766): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
07-28 20:53:01.692: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2766): CheckJNI is ON
07-28 20:53:02.023: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2766): --- registering native functions ---
07-28 20:53:05.083: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2766): Shutting down VM
```

Does anyone have a clue WTF is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like one of the framework-interaction shell commands is being launched repeatedly.  If you type "adb shell am" you'll see similar output in the log file.  Something in your development environment is going nutty.

Are you using Windows or Linux?  Eclipse?  The Android ADT plugin?

You can try "adb kill-server" to see if that's enough of a reset to stop whatever is going batty.

Comment: Running Eclipse 3.5/WinXP. Stopping and starting the emulator fixed it, but if it happens again I'll take a look at that shell log. Thanks!